# ZipPackage to create a ZIP of many files - any problems?

Tags: .net

My ASP.NET app has to create a ZIP file that will consist of several files.
I do not want to use external libraries. In .NET I have found only ZipPackage. It always adds file '[Content_Types].xml' automatically, but this is acceptable for me.
However - did not I overlook any other possible problems with ZipPackage?

Answer (score 1):

you can also use Gzipstream or deflatestream

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx

Comment: sorry, forgot to say: I use .NET v 3.5. In this version Gzipstream  does not support multiple files, correct?